# Pulling certain data information out of a Cell

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract

```
Cheetah Piss - (3.5g) - Artizen
```

Trying to use a function that would be able to locate the information inside of the () so in this case is a 3.5g.  I can't seem to get a function to pull it, I've gotten some to do close or 1 half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regex:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "\((.*)\)")
```

[image]

for array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "\((.*)\)")))
```

---

```
.        - one single character
.*       - all of it
(.*)     - get everything
\(       - escaped parenthesis
\)       - escaped parenthesis
\((.*)\) - get everything inside parenthesis
```

Comment: Could you explain the "\((.*)\)" part of that?  i just want to get a better understanding on how to tell to what to do, im reading that and im just not understanding why its doing what its doing.  It is the solution tho

Comment: @JamesKeetch sure. answer updated

Comment: So one last additional situation. so if i wanted to remove the g as well, would i change it it to have a "g" in place of a (?  i cant seem to get it to work as well... thank you for your time.

Comment: @JamesKeetch https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVBX6.png